# Unable to remove file on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, csh

I'm currently connected to a remote computer running on Linux and I have a random directory that arose after running one of my C programs. The directory name is of this form: 'H$'204'blahblah''u$'[]'$'234', very strange.

When I try to remove it via `rm dir_name` the terminal spits out `Illegal variable name.` The same behavior arises even when I use the `-f` flag. Then I attempted to remove it by clicking on the directory in the explorer (on vscode) and I get an error saying `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory.`

I'm running this on csh shell if that helps.

**Update:** Running: `rm ./H<tab>` worked. Thanks to [Jamie Guinan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488095/jamieguinan)!

Comment: Try running `rm ./H<tab>` and see if it tab completes the name for you. Also, in your program, make sure you initialize your variables before calling mkdir().

Comment: This was legendary. This worked for me, one of the slashes was actually supposed to face in the other direction.

Comment: Try rm "'H$'204'blahblah''u$'[]'$'234"

Comment: In such situations I'm using mc (midnight commander) file manager. It is the most reliable way. Once I've found a file which had "\n" (new line) in the name. I've realized it only when browsing with mc.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word is `ls -b`. It will display non printable characters in an escaped way, so that you will be able to enter them back.

Comment: I used this command, copied the output for the specific directory and then attemped to remove it but then still get the same behavior; i.e., No such file or directory.

Comment: You will have to escape any special character, at least (from your example) `$'` and depending on the shell you are using maybe `[]` too.